# scrollview inside a textview (rate snippet)

Tags: android

I discoverd the snipped to do a rate of own app: http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater

Personalizing this code I can't insert a scrollview (no xml but using java code) inside a textview created by the snipped:

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
    tv.setWidth(240);
    tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
    ll.addView(tv);
```

Comment: You want to put a scroll view inside a text view?  Huh?  Sorry, your question is not clear to me...

Comment: yep! A scroll view within text view (a text view scrollable). Thanks!

Comment: To have a scrollable TextView, if that is what you want, you put a TextView inside a ScrollView.  If you have more than one thing inside a ScrollView, you have to put them both inside another layout, like a LinearLayout, and then put that LinearLayout inside the ScrollView.  Make sense?  There's no such thing as a TextViewScrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the TextView inside another Layout (as you do) and then everything within the ScrollView. To do so:

```
ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(mContext);
sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
sc.setFillViewport(true);

sc.addView(ll);
```

Comment: That would work for a text view in a scroll view (which can only allow one child, this case a LL), but he wrote it as the other way around (perhaps grammatical error?): "I can't insert a scrollview (no xml but using java code) inside a textview"

Comment: That's right. I agree with you that's why I have voted your comment up.

Comment: Assuming you mean text view in scroll view, your scroll view can only have one child.  Meaning you can't add more than one LL (or any other type) into the scroll view.  You have to put all the children inside of the single child of the scrollview (which as depicted in the example above would be a linear layout).  But still, can you clarify that is what you mean, because you can't really put a scrollview in a textview (unless you use a framelayout and overlay, but that's a different story).  We are just making guesses here!

Comment: not to easy for me! I'd better go to study! thanks for your help! :-)